# Upload Files to Azure Storage from Azure Function - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

Currently I'm sending a file from Angular as a blob using formdata like so

```
  uploadFiles(file) {
    let testData: FormData = new FormData();
    testData.append('file_upload', file, file.name);
    console.log("TESTDATA", file);
    console.log(file);
    return this.http
      .post<{ message: string; listingId: string; creator: string }>(
        environment.azure_function_url + `/UploadFilesTest`,
        testData
      );
  }
```

I'm able to receive it in the azure function by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50565239/4350389)
in my azure function, but I'm not sure how to get from here to azure blob. I'm not sure what I would pass into blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile to get the file to blob storage. I tried passing the `parts` and `image` variables but it keeps saying `Parameter blob for function _createBlobFromLocalFile should be a non-empty string`
If I return the commented out code at the bottom then the frontend returns

[image]

which seems promising to me that I'm on the right track, butI just don't know how to get this to play nice with `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile()` function. I appreciate any help!

```
var multipart = require("parse-multipart");
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_AUCTIONIMAGESACCOUNT, process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_AZURE_STORAGE_AUCTIONIMAGESACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

module.exports = function (context, req) {

  // encode body to base64 string
  var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);

  var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
  // parse the body
  var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
  console.log(parts)
  let image = [{ name: parts[0].filename, type: parts[0].type, data: parts[0].data.length }];
  // context.res = { body: { name: parts[0].filename, type: parts[0].type, data: parts[0].data.length, "TEST": "TEST" } };
  // context.done();
  // return;

  blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('auctionimages', image, 'image.png', function (error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
      // file uploaded
    }
  });


};
```

Comment: Is using `formidable` an option? I answered a similar question a few days ago where I used that package.

Comment: As long as I can get it working, I don't care how it's done lol. I did read that azure functions are a little tricky when dealing with files so I'm not sure if formidable will work, but I'm no expert

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423408/images-uploaded-with-node-corrupted.

Comment: Azure functions are setup a little different. The person in that answer also mentions this ```I had to tune it for Azure functions```  so I need an azure function focused solution. I'm not sure this will work for me

Comment: @user6680 please refer to https://medium.com/@rkmusic75/uploading-image-multipart-to-azure-blob-from-azure-functions-streamifier-parse-multipart-79d9d679adef

Comment: @JimXu I looked at that article and It got me farther. I was able to add a file to storage blob, but it stores the image file with the name blob https://postimg.cc/1nkxZmrs and it's no longer an image. Here's my updated code and console output https://pastebin.com/X281tp8Y  Do you know what my issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the blob as image in Azure blob storage, you want to set the blob content type by creating `CreateBlockBlobRequestOptions` when we upload file with the method `createBlockBlobFromStream`.
[image]

For example

```
const streamifier = require('streamifier');
const multipart = require('parse-multipart');
const azure = require('azure-storage');

module.exports =  function (context, req) {
  var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
  var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
  var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);

  var filedata = parts[0].data;         // Image buffer data
  var filename = parts[0].filename;     // testImage.png
  console.log("parts[0].data");
  console.log(parts[0].data);
  console.log("parts[0].filename");
  console.log(parts[0].filename);
  const accountname ="blobstorage0516";
  const key = "eGier5YJBzr5z3xgOJUb+sn***7Csvgx75NwiOZE7kYLJfLqWBg==";
  const containerName="test1";
  const blobClient  =azure.createBlobService(accountname,key);
 # set blob content type
  var options = {
    contentSettings:{contentType: parts[0].type}
  };
  blobClient.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName,filename,streamifier.createReadStream(new Buffer(filedata)), filedata.length,options,(err,result)=>{

    if (!err) {
        console.log("Image upload successful", result);

    } else{

      throw err;
    }
  })
  context.res = {
    // status defaults to 200 */
    body: "ok"
};
context.done();
};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I updated my code using your answer and it uploads to storage: https://postimg.cc/LhQh8hVV. It shows image/jpeg as content-type, but file lacks file extension. If I click the file to view it from storage, then it says ```the image <URL> can't be displayed because it contained errors.``` I think it's related to ```console.log(parts[0].filename)``` that outputs the value ```blob``` instead of something like ```testImage.png```  It's not accessing filename property correctly, but it does have the array buffer coming in as you can see from my console.log https://pastebin.com/ise1z5CM . Any ideas?

Comment: @user6680, `parts[0].filename` will get the vault of your `File` object's name in the `Formdata`. According to the picture you provide, the file name is blob

Comment: So apparently it doesn't work when being sent from my Angular application, but it does work from postman. I sent a file from postman and it worked perfectly, but from my app I have the problem I've been experiencing, which means it's related to how I'm sending the file I'm guessing I have to send the file in a different format from Angular other than blob type. I believe blob is the type. ```console.log("imageData", file.name)``` outputs https://postimg.cc/8sTr5jrF ```console.log("imageData", file);```  outputs https://postimg.cc/hhR10DQg  Updated angular service: https://pastebin.com/k2heZrrP

Comment: @user6680 please try to send a file from your angular application as a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) type to Azure function. For more details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload